# Performance issues with Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

I want to draw on a bitmap using Canvas.
I tested it on my phone and it appeared to be very slow and it felt like if I drew fast it didn't register the whole movement but only parts of it.
Since I want it to very detailed I need to use bitmaps
How can I improve my performance?

```
        public class DrawView extends View {
        public Bitmap  mBitmap;
        public Canvas  mCanvas;
        private Path    mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
        private Paint   mPaint;


        public DrawView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(c, attrs);

            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setDither(true);
            mPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(9);

        }


        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);


        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If touch events go faster, then `onDraw`, then you don't need to draw every time you have new point, you should draw, when it's actually asked to - in `onDraw` method.
Although, skia (which is android canvas based on) is not so fast to draw so many quads. You can draw simple batch of lines, but form these lines as centripethal Catmull-Rom splines or some splines, which is better for you.

And more, `Path` can store not so much lines

Comment: Isn't the onDraw method called whenever i call invalidate()?
So how could I change that since i always have to call invalidate when i touch the screen.

Furthermore do you mean that all of my drawn 'Paths' are stored basically as an array and it gets too big?

Thanks for your answer btw